# failed to open stream: Permission denied warning while load_textdomain

Tags: localization

While achieving localization of my theme, I am getting a warning:

> Warning: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs/wp-content/themes/themename/languages): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\pomo\streams.php on line 145

When I comment line for loading text_domain in functions.php as follows:
    `load_textdomain( 'themename', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );`
aforementioned warning doesn't show up.

I have uploaded required .po and .mo files in `themename/languages` folder.
I have also set `WP_LAN`G to `hi_IN` in `WP-CONFIG.php`

I am using xampp installation of WordPress on localhost on my windows machine.
PHP Version 5.5.11
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
So how can I get rid of this warning and achieve localization?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **load_textdomain** you must also specify the file name:

```
function my_custom_locale() 
{
    load_textdomain('my-name', get_stylesheet_directory().'/languages/my-name-
    '.get_locale().'.mo');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_locale');
```

In my example I added custom translations used in additional template files placed inside the **theme-child** folder, where I also added the **languages** files folder (es. my-name-it_IT.mo, my-name-en_GB.mo).

I added the code in the function.php file of the child-theme.

Answer (score 0):

I made a huge mistake by using function `load_textdomain`. While typing the code I used the auto suggest function in Sublime-Text and got it all wrong. So use `load_theme_textdomain`